# firebase signInWithRedirect with microsoft oauth provider encounters 400 and immediately redirects to original page

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory, google-identity

I have have an GCP Identity Platform + Firebase app using a Microsoft Active Directory Oauth Provider.

When calling `signInWithRedirect` it gets a 400 with the url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/createAuthUri?key=<api-key>
```

(note, I am redacting my specific values)

The payload it sends looks like

```
{
  "providerId": "microsoft.com",
  "continueUri": "https://<my-gcp-project-id>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler",
  "customParameter": { "tenant": "<my-domain>", "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3000/callback" }
}
```

Config

```
const config = {
  apiKey: "<api-key>",
  authDomain: "<my-domain>",
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const firebaseAuthApp = firebaseAuth.getAuth(firebaseApp)
const provider = new firebaseAuth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
provider.setCustomParameters({
  tenant: 'mydomain.com',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
});
```

Triggering auth:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  firebaseAuth.signInWithRedirect(firebaseAuthApp, provider)
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you refer to this link :https://stackoverflow.com/a/43491949/15774176 Is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav unfortunately this seems to be a separate issue

Comment: are you following these steps : https://medium.com/@alex.wauters/how-to-integrate-a-firebase-web-app-with-azure-active-directory-b5c0f01a0c24 ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an incorrect redirect URI defined in the Azure console Active Directory application configuration.

To get my app working (locally) I provided the firebase auth handler callback:
[image]

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50011-reply-url-mismatch